# Server Discovery And Monitoring engine is deprecated, previous post doesn't help out

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, server, winston, mongoose-web-server

`enter code here`(node:20092) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created).

No previous solution works for me . Which i shown .
This are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "fawn": "^2.1.5",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "npm": "^6.14.13",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popups": "^1.1.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-mongodb": "^5.0.7"
  },
```